# Use of unresolved identifier in same IBAction as defined

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm new to swift and don't know why it doesn't recognize `print(right_answer)` even though it is in the same `IBAction` function as it's declaration.

```
@IBAction func answer_three(_ sender: Any) {
    if randomnumber1 == 2  {
        var right_answer = true

    } else {
        let right_answer = true

    }
    //Error "Use of unresolved identifier 'right_answer' on line below
    print(right_answer)
}
```

If you need more info or code just let me know.

Comment: You should declare right_answer outside if-else statement or you should write the print method in if-else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have curly braces, it defines a local scope. When you leave the curly braces, you exit that scope. If you define a variable inside a set of curly braces, it only exists inside those curly braces.

Move the declaration of your variable right_answer to the top of the function, like this:

```
@IBAction func answer_three(_ sender: Any) -> Bool {
    var right_answer: Bool
    if randomnumber1 == 2  {
       right_answer = true
    } else {
       right_answer = true
    }
    print(right_answer)
    return right_answer
}
```

(Your original code sets right_answer to true in all cases, which doesn't make much sense. I left it that way since I don't know what you **want** it to do.)

Note that the variable right_answer is still local to the function. When you exit the function, that variable goes out of scope and the variable no longer exists. (That's ok, because what you care about is the returned value of the function.)

The idea of local and global scope is a programming fundamental. You should read a book on programming. Apple's Swift programming iBook would be a good choice. It teaches you programming from the beginning using Swift.

Comment: You can even write `let right_answer: Bool` because it's actually initialized as a constant

Comment: Yup. I thought about suggesting that.

Comment: True. Methinks that was a typo though, and that would kill the lesson on local scope.